# Run Experiment via Feature and get VariationId of Experiment

Tags: growthbook

Playing around with growthbook, and having a hard time, figuring out how to use experiments.

- created experiment.
- created feature, with experiment rule

now my feature has variations, and my experiment have variations.

in JS-Land, i do something like:

```
const growthbook = new GrowthBook({
  apiHost: "http://localhost:3100",
  clientKey: "sdk-ZzfdzxSSDuHgmpXG",
  enableDevMode: true,
  trackingCallback: (experiment, result) => {
    console.log("Viewed Experiment", {
      experimentId: experiment.key,
      variationId: result.variationId
    });

  }
});

growthbook.setAttributes({
    user_id: "ccc",
    id: "cccc"
  });
  await growthbook.loadFeatures({ autoRefresh: true });

  if (growthbook.isOn("my-test")) {
    console.log("Feature is enabled!");
  }
```

it works, but in fact the `variationId`  in the console.log is actually the variation ID of the Feature itself.

question: how to get the variation id of the experiment, or what is the best way to run a experiment.

not quiet sure, how to trigger experiments, and how they are connected. (i understand, metric tracking and conversion tracking - but that requires to get the variationId)

or is it supposed to be - that variationId's on feature need to be done too on experiment?!

[image: Experiment]

[image: Feature]

[image: console]

Answer (score 0):

It seems impossible to know the "name" of the variant, as it is not exposed.

But with `growthBook.getFeatureValue("my-test")` you get the value of the current variation. Depending which "value type" was selected when creating the feature, the value can be either boolean, json, number or a string. In your case the result would be a string with either "variation1", "variation2" and so on.